# Make another math quiz appear if a JButton "Next" is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, layout-manager

I'm doing a Math Quiz program by using GUI. This is my code, my problem now is:

1. How to make another question appear if the `JButton` <kbd>Next</kbd> is pressed.
2. How to make the <kbd>Next</kbd> button work if and only if the answer is correct? (means that they must answer correctly before move to next question).

Someone help me please, thank you.

```
public class MathQuiz extends JFrame{

    JButton jbtNum1, jbtNum2, jbtNum3, jbtNum4, jbtNum5, jbtNum6, jbtNum7, jbtNum8, jbtNum9, jbtNum10, jbtNum11, jbtNum12, jbtNum13, jbtNum14, jbtNum15, jbtNum16, jbtNum17, jbtNum18, jbtNum19, jbtNum20;
    JButton jbtConfirm;
    JButton jbtNext;
    JTextField jtfAnswer = new JTextField();
    int a = (int)((Math.random())*10);
    int b = (int)((Math.random())*10);

    public MathQuiz(){

        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4,1,1));

            p1.add(jbtNum1 = new JButton("10"));
            p1.add(jbtNum2 = new JButton("7"));
            p1.add(jbtNum3 = new JButton("2"));
            p1.add(jbtNum4 = new JButton("18"));
            p1.add(jbtNum5 = new JButton("6"));
            p1.add(jbtNum6 = new JButton("11"));
            p1.add(jbtNum7 = new JButton("14"));
            p1.add(jbtNum8 = new JButton("1"));
            p1.add(jbtNum9 = new JButton("9"));
            p1.add(jbtNum10 = new JButton("3"));
            p1.add(jbtNum11 = new JButton("16"));
            p1.add(jbtNum12 = new JButton("17"));
            p1.add(jbtNum13 = new JButton("8"));
            p1.add(jbtNum14 = new JButton("15"));
            p1.add(jbtNum15 = new JButton("13"));
            p1.add(jbtNum16 = new JButton("5"));
            p1.add(jbtNum17 = new JButton("20"));
            p1.add(jbtNum18 = new JButton("12"));
            p1.add(jbtNum19 = new JButton("19"));
            p1.add(jbtNum20 = new JButton("4"));

        JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,5));

        p2.add(new JLabel(" " + a));
        p2.add(new JLabel(" + "));
        p2.add(new JLabel(" " + b));
        p2.add(new JLabel(" = "));
        p2.add(jtfAnswer);
        jtfAnswer.setEditable(false);
        p2.add(jbtConfirm = new JButton("Confirm"));
        p2.add(jbtNext = new JButton("Next"));

        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1,50,50));
        add(p1);
        add(p2);

        jbtNum1.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum2.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum3.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum4.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum5.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum6.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum7.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum8.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum9.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum10.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum11.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum12.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum13.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum14.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum15.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum16.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum17.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum18.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum19.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtNum20.addActionListener(new ListenToButton());
        jbtConfirm.addActionListener(new ListenToConfirm());
    }

    class ListenToButton implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == jbtNum1)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum1.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum2)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum2.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum3)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum3.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum4)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum4.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum5)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum5.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum6)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum6.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum7)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum7.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum8)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum8.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum9)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum9.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum10)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum10.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum11)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum11.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum12)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum12.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum13)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum13.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum14)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum14.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum15)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum15.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum16)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum16.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum17)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum17.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum18)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum18.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum19)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum19.getText());
            else if(e.getSource() == jbtNum20)
                jtfAnswer.setText(jbtNum20.getText());
        }
    }

    class ListenToConfirm implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            int answer = a + b;
            int guessAnswer = Integer.parseInt(jtfAnswer.getText());

            if(guessAnswer == answer)
                jtfAnswer.setText("Correct");
            else
                jtfAnswer.setText("Wrong! Try Again.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        MathQuiz frame = new MathQuiz();
        frame.setTitle("Math Quiz");
        frame.setSize(700,500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the question or did I miss it? All I see is a bunch of buttons and one text field.

Comment: ChadNC, I set the question in JPanel p2

Answer (score 3):

To solve your problem 1, use [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). To solve your problem 2, use simple `if` statement.

Comment: An alternative for 2 is 'disable it until the answer is correct'.

Answer (score 3):

1. Instead of using four JLabels you could use only one and call the setText() method on the JLabel when the answer is correct and you wish to display a different question.

   JLabel question = new JLabel("your first question");
2. When you create the JButton disable it.

Disable the button on creation.

```
    jbtNext = new JButton("Next");
    jbtNext.setEnabled(false);// button is initially disabled
```

In your ActionListener for the confirm button

```
   if(guessAnswer == answer){
        jtfAnswer.setText("Correct"); 
        jbtNext.setEnabled(true);
   }else 
       jtfAnswer.setText("Wrong! Try Again.");
```

You'll need to add an ActionListener to the "Next" button also.

```
jbtNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      question.setText("Your next question");// change the question text
      jbtNext.setEnabled(false);// disable again until the next correct answer
    }
  });
```